# Pivot Table -- How to pass Metric as Filter when viewing Raw Data

Tags: excel

Let's say I have the following data in Excel:

[image]

```
Book    Country Book Store  Book Is New?
Hamlet  US  Amazon  0
Hamlet  CA  Amazon  0
Hamlet  US  Barnes & Noble  0
Hamlet  CA  Barnes & Noble  0
Harry Potter 1  US  Amazon  1
Harry Potter 1  CA  Amazon  1
Harry Potter 1  US  Barnes & Noble  1
Harry Potter 1  CA  Barnes & Noble  1
Harry Potter 2  US  Amazon  1
Harry Potter 2  CA  Amazon  1
Harry Potter 2  US  Barnes & Noble  1
Harry Potter 2  CA  Barnes & Noble  1
```

I would like to create a Pivot Table to get the number of "New Books" per Book Store - Country combination. For example, the number of "New Books" on Amazon-US would be two -- Harry Potter 1 and Harry Potter 2. Here is the Pivot Table I have:

[image]

However, when I click into any of the metrics to get the raw data. It gives me all books at that cell-intersection. For example, if I click the Amazon-US new releases, which shows 2, it will produce 3 results, basically ignoring how the calculation is done, and passing the filters from the Rows (Amazon) and Columns (US):

[image]

Is there a way (even if it's hack-ish) to be able to pass the filter of "Book Is New?" when double-clicking a value. In other words, if it says 2, and I click it, it should show 2 data rows, instead of 3. Attached is the xlsx workbook if helpful: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uqdll138fcsfsse/SO_Example.xlsx?dl=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Show Details* feature produces a subset of the source table whose entries match the current `filter context` for the chosen value. As you currently have it set up, both *Book Store* (via the Pivot Table *Rows* field) and *Country* (via the Pivot Table *Columns* field) make up part of that filter context. *Book Is New?*, however, is not applying any filter context.

In order to make it so, you could place that field in either the *Filters* area of the Pivot Table or else in a *Slicer* and set it to 1.

Comment: right, that is the workaround I'm doing (currently adding it to filters). Is there any ability in Excel to pass an additional filter when clicking into a cell (without using something like VBA)?

Comment: Without VBA, no.